# On spotlight, typing 'message' autocompletes to Messages but 'messages' goes to Minecraft

Tags: spotlight

That's it. What's going on and how do I fix it? 
[image: Message]
[image: Messages]

Comment: There's some metadata associated with, or files buried in the application bundle of, Minecraft that causes it to be the first result for the word "messages". There's nothing you can do to change spotlight results, other than deleting the Minecraft app bundle. Alternatively, use something like [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/), which starts to learn if you type "messages" and select the Messages app, that it should come up first instead of Minecraft. Spotlight does not have this learning capability as far as I know.